# UITableView section header inset missing

Tags: ios, uitableview, insets

How do I fix the problem illustrated in the image?

The section header for the tableview is missing an inset.

[image: section header for the tableview is missing an inset.]

Comment: Have you tried going to the Size Inspector and changing the height of the header?

Comment: No, tried it but it didn't help. Thanks though!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You probably set the separator insets to 0, either in code or in the Interface Builder (can be found in the Attributes inspector:

[image: Separator insets set to 0]

This also causes the titles to have no inset. The default values are 15 for left and 0 for right.

Comment: thanks! I wasn't doing that in IB, but i was calling """if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(separatorInset)]) {
[self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}"""

Answer (score 5):

[Could you post your code of `UITableViewDelegate`?
In `UITableView`, there is no API for you to set this insets in section header, so you could return a custom `UIView` in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` then set the layout you want.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [UIView alloc] init];
    UILabel *headerLabel = [UILabel alloc] init];
    headerLabel.text = @"xxx";
    [headerLabel sizeToFit];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 0, CGRectGetWidth(headerLabel.frame), CGRectGetHeight(headerLabel.frame));
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];
    headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(headerLabel.frame));
    return headerView;
}
```